# Visual Basic Input Box Loop Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops

I'm quite new to VB. I'm trying to insert a new record after an input box (Event triggering is Button click). I've got that to work fine, it updates the SQL server.

I then tried to add a loop, with a simple vbYesNo message box, with vbYes triggering the loop. It's not working, it's looping no matter if you click yes or no.

I was hoping it would (On pressing yes), prompt for two barcodes, then it would insert the new record. However I'm getting an error saying "This row already belongs to this table", when I've just added it.

Any help?

Here's the code:

```
    Do While vbYes
        TrackCode = InputBox("Please Scan Shipment Barcode")
        NewRecord(5) = TrackCode
        NewRecord(0) = Ddate
        UnqCode = InputBox("Please Scan Parcel Barcode (eg JD123456789)")
        NewRecord(6) = UnqCode
        DtTable.Rows.Add(NewRecord)
        NewRecord.AcceptChanges()
        DtTable.AcceptChanges()
        TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(trackingDataSet)
        MsgBox("Do You Have Anything Else To Scan?", vbYesNo)
 Loop
```

Sorry if it's something simple. Also all the `AcceptChanges()` are due to me trying to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add the same row over and over again.

Comment: Yeah, What I am trying to do is actually add a new row each time they click yes, not edit the same row.

Comment: So then why is it in a loop?  And what is the exit condition of the loop?

Comment: Because at one time, the user may add multiple shipments in one go. I didn't know I needed an exit condition. I was under the assumption that the Do While vbYes would be the only condition to carry it on. I was under the impression by selecting "No", the loop would exit?

Comment: Yes, that will exit the loop.

Comment: For some reason it's not exiting when I select No on the MessageBox with VBYesNo. Any idea why? I can't understand why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming  DtTable is a DataTable and NewRecord is a DataRow, try adding the very first line inside of loop:

```
NewRecord = DtTable.NewRow()
```

This will create a new data row on every iteration.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now I've just got to sort out the looping issue. I knew it would be something simple though -.-